# Problem with Piping for revalue in R Studio

Tags: r, pipe

I would like to revalue 13 different variables. They all have character as levels right now and are supposed to be changed to values.
Individually it would work to use

```
x$eins <- revalue(x$eins, c("Nie Thema" = "1",
                "Selten Thema" = "2",
                "Manchmal Thema" = "3", 
                "Häufig Thema" = "4",
                "Sehr häufig Thema" = "5",
                "Fast immer Thema" = "6"))
```

With the piping, I guess it would look something like this

```
x %>% 
  dplyr::select(., eins:dreizehn) %>% 
  revalue(., c("Nie Thema" = "1",
                "Selten Thema" = "2",
                "Manchmal Thema" = "3", 
                "Häufig Thema" = "4",
                "Sehr häufig Thema" = "5",
                "Fast immer Thema" = "6"))
```

With this, I get the warning message from revalue, that  x is not a factor or a character vector.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier to sort this out if you provide a toy problem with data where people and try out the behavior of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `across` to apply a function for multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- x %>%
      dplyr::mutate(across(eins:dreizehn, ~revalue(., c("Nie Thema" = "1",
                                                 "Selten Thema" = "2",
                                                 "Manchmal Thema" = "3", 
                                                 "Häufig Thema" = "4",
                                                 "Sehr häufig Thema" = "5",
                                                 "Fast immer Thema" = "6"))))
```